# Non-square matrix with a sub-matrix of zeros: finding determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-rank, control-theory

I'm looking at controllability matricies and determining if they are full rank.

One example has a non-square (4 x 8) controllability matrix (A|C) where A = (4x4) and C = zeros(4x4). To find the determinant, the question ignores the zero sub-matrix (C) and finds the determinant of A (the non-zero sub matrix).

[Controllability matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d65K1.jpg)

Can anyone explain why this is possible?
Thanks!

Comment: You ask why a 4x8 matrix comprised of a 4x4 zero matrix and another 4x4 matrix $A$ is full rank iff the 4x4 matrix $A$ has nonzero determinant?  What do you know about determinants with regard to rank?

Comment: The punchline is that $A$ will have nonzero determinant iff $A$ is full rank.  And $A$ having full rank will imply your $4\times 8$ matrix will also be full rank.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for your response! Could you elaborate as to why A having full rank implies the larger matrix also having full rank?

Comment: Because being full rank implies the four rows of $A$ are linearly independent.  The four rows of your original matrix are still going to be linearly independent since appending zeroes does not change this fact.  Your original matrix then has four linearly independent rows and so is full rank.

Comment: @JMoravitz That makes sense! Thank you for explaining